# Laravel redirect does not work when posting to Laravel from Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Write my example below.

Currently, I am in /user/edit.

Laravel Api code

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
  /** here update user code **/

  return redirect()->to('/home')
}
```

Vue code

```
axios.post('/api/user/' + this.userId, formData).then(res => {
  console.log('success!')
}
```

However, no redirection is performed. I am still in /user/edit.

In the case of Laravel and Vue configuration, when posting via API, do I have to write the redirect process in Vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I have to write the redirect process in Vue?

Yes, you are right. You can do it via `window.location.href = '/home';` inside your callback.